# Is there an official name for a wooden spiked wall?

Tags: creative-writing

I’ve looked it up but all I can find is that it’s called a wooden spiked wall

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockade ? this is off-topic for writing.SE though

Comment: Please note that requests for words that are not specifically about writing terminology are off-topic on Writing.SE and in general on-topic on [ELU.SE]. You might want to check out their site and have a look at their help center and tour to see if they might be more helpful for your request.

Answer (score 5):

It's called a palisade.

palisade
NOUN
1 A fence of wooden stakes or iron railings fixed in the ground, forming an enclosure or defence.

I've also seen it called a fort wall. Or a wooden fort wall or a wooden palisade or stockade as @TotumusMaximus says.

Comment: I meant like the ones in the walking dead were the spikes are faced outwards

Comment: Ahh, I think that's called a cheval-de-frise. It often helps to post a photo so people know exactly what you're asking for. HTH!